# Como permitir obter dados via API do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, react

Queria começar a aprender React.js e para isso decidi fazer um tema escrito em React para o meu wordpress, usando a 'nova' funcionalidade WP API. Como faço para ter acesso ao API a partir do meu computador? Eu sei que tenho de autorizar a chamada à API, mas não sei como fazer. Veja como estou a tentar buscar as informações:

```
componentDidMount() {
let dataURL = "http://meusite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/books?_embed";
fetch(dataURL)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      movies: res
    })
  })
}
```

Recebo o erro 425 (visivel do chrome devTools) quando faço a chamada para o Url que devolve Json.

Como posso permitir o acesso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rotas de leitura sempre serão públicas no wordpress a não ser que você aplique um filtro para protegê-las..  Ler a lista de posts por exemplo, seja para custom post type ou não você não precisa de autenticar..

as rotas para adicionar novos conteúdos no banco, vc precisa de autenticação..

Usando o oauth2 você vai ter bastante trabalho pra compreender se você não estiver familiarizado.. Você pode optar em usar o JWT para fazer essa autenticação.. Seja qual for o modo de autenticação que você utilizar, você vai precisar instalar o plugin..